# jQuery animate scrollLeft works in every browser except Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have some code that is scrolling a div horizontally when the scroll right (#nexty) or scroll left (#prevy) arrow is clicked on (a test site example is here: http://abmo.stephensuess.com/project/hi-lo-bbq/), and it works in latest Safari, Firefox, IE...but not in Chrome. In Chrome, it will advance on the FIRST click, but then will not advance on any subsequent click. In the other browsers it continues to advance as expected.

Here is the javascript code:

```
<script>$(window).load(function(){
  var currentElement = $("#ngg-gallery-list > div:nth-child(2)");
var onScroll = function () {
    //get the current element
    var container = $("#ngg-galleryoverview");
    var wrapper = $("#ngg-gallery-list");
    var children = wrapper.children();
    var position = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        var child = $(children[i]);
        var childLeft = container.offset().left < child.offset().left;
        if (childLeft) {
            currentElement = child;
            console.log(currentElement)
            return;
        }
    }
}

var scrollToElement = function ($element) {
    var container = $("#ngg-galleryoverview");
    var wrapper = $("#ngg-gallery-list");
    var children = wrapper.children();
    var width = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        var child = $(children[i]);
        if (child.get(0) == $element.get(0)) {
            if (i == 0) {
                width = 300;
            }
            container.animate({
                scrollLeft: width
            }, 300);
            onScroll();
        }
        if (child.next().length > 0) {
            //make sure we factor in borders/padding/margin in height
            width += child.next().offset().left - child.offset().left
        } else {
            width += child.width();
        }
    }
}

var next = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    scrollToElement(currentElement);
}

var prev = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var container = $("#ngg-galleryoverview");
    if (currentElement.prev().length > 0) {
        if (container.offset().left == currentElement.prev().offset().left) {
            currentElement = currentElement.prev().prev().length > 0 ? currentElement.prev().prev() : currentElement.prev();
        } else {
            currentElement = currentElement.prev();
        }
    }
    scrollToElement(currentElement);
}

$("#ngg-galleryoverview").scroll(onScroll);
$("#nexty").click(next);
$("#prevy").click(prev);
});
</script>
```

Here is the html code:

```
 <div id="ngg-galleryoverview"> 
    <div id="ngg-gallery-list" style="width: 4282px;">

        <!-- Thumbnail list -->

        <div id="0" class="list">
                <img class="lazy" src="http://abmo.stephensuess.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Hi-Lo-Signage-600-737x425.jpg" data-original="http://abmo.stephensuess.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Hi-Lo-Signage-600-737x425.jpg" data-original-width="737" data-original-height="425" style="height: 425px; display: inline;">
            <div class="noinfotext"></div>      </div>


        <div id="1" class="list">
                <img class="lazy" src="http://abmo.stephensuess.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Shosugiban-wall-600-638x425.jpg" data-original="http://abmo.stephensuess.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Shosugiban-wall-600-638x425.jpg" data-original-width="638" data-original-height="425" style="height: 425px; display: inline;">
            <div class="noinfotext"></div>      </div>


        <div id="2" class="list">
                <img class="lazy" src="http://abmo.stephensuess.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/HILO-Counter-Display-288x425.jpg" data-original="http://abmo.stephensuess.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/HILO-Counter-Display-288x425.jpg" data-original-width="288" data-original-height="425" style="height: 425px; display: inline;">
            <div class="noinfotext"></div>      </div>


        <div id="3" class="list">
                <img class="lazy" src="http://abmo.stephensuess.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/HILO-STEEL-Shelf-600-276x425.jpg" data-original="http://abmo.stephensuess.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/HILO-STEEL-Shelf-600-276x425.jpg" data-original-width="276" data-original-height="425" style="height: 425px; display: inline;">
            <div class="noinfotext"></div>      </div>


        <div id="4" class="list">
                <img class="lazy" src="http://abmo.stephensuess.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Hi-Lo-Overall-B-600-638x425.jpg" data-original="http://abmo.stephensuess.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Hi-Lo-Overall-B-600-638x425.jpg" data-original-width="638" data-original-height="425" style="height: 425px; display: inline;">
            <div class="noinfotext"></div>      </div>


        <div id="5" class="list">
                <img class="lazy" src="http://abmo.stephensuess.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Hi-Lo-Card-600-283x425.jpg" data-original="http://abmo.stephensuess.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Hi-Lo-Card-600-283x425.jpg" data-original-width="283" data-original-height="425" style="height: 425px; display: inline;">
            <div class="noinfotext"></div>      </div>


        <div id="6" class="list">
                <img class="lazy" src="http://abmo.stephensuess.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Bottle-Details-447x425.jpg" data-original="http://abmo.stephensuess.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Bottle-Details-447x425.jpg" data-original-width="447" data-original-height="425" style="height: 425px; display: inline;">
            <div class="noinfotext"></div>      </div>


        <div id="7" class="list">
                <img class="lazy" src="http://abmo.stephensuess.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Amber-Bottle-Chandelier-600-638x425.jpg" data-original="http://abmo.stephensuess.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Amber-Bottle-Chandelier-600-638x425.jpg" data-original-width="638" data-original-height="425" style="height: 425px; display: inline;">
            <div class="noinfotext"></div>      </div>


        <div id="8" class="list">
                <img class="lazy" src="http://abmo.stephensuess.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/HILO-LEG-283x425.jpg" data-original="http://abmo.stephensuess.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/HILO-LEG-283x425.jpg" data-original-width="283" data-original-height="425" style="height: 425px; display: inline;">
            <div class="noinfotext"></div>      </div>

            </div>
</div> <div id="projectnav"> 
<a href="#" class="masterTooltip" id="prevy" title="scroll left"><div id="previousimages"></div></a> 
<a href="#" class="masterTooltipScroll" id="nexty" title="scroll right"><div id="nextimages"></div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Only because of `z-index` of `id="projectnav"` .

Comment: if that were the case, why would the first click in chrome work, and why would it work in all other browsers?

Comment: see the added answer

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one:** working for all browser.

```
#projectnav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 500;
  top: -40px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

Remove `height:40px;` and add `margin-bottom:40px;`

**Correction:**

```
#projectnav {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 500;
  top: -40px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: This is temparary solution for you

Comment: @Stephen looks like this is working fine in your site with `margin-bottom:40px` for `#projectnav` : http://abmo.stephensuess.com/project/hi-lo-bbq/  if still issue in your side then let me know which Version of chrome you are using ?

Comment: I now think it may be related to the chrome version, I am using 43.0.2357.81 (64-bit), but in testing yesterday a friend of mine using 42 did not have the problem. What version are you using?

Comment: I just downloaded the beta (44.0.2403.18 beta (64-bit)) and it seems to be fixed. So it was a bug in the latest Chrome, definitely.

Comment: I am using 43.0.2357.81 m , it same as your old version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79000/discussion-between-sachink-and-stephen).